# Simple Thread Synchronization Issue

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

In below code, it doesn't make a difference in output if I synchronize the `bar` method or not - what am I doing wrong?  I believe that synchronizing "bar" will make "ThreaOne" to be printed 10 times and then only printing "ThreadTwo" will start, but it is not the case. The ouput I get is as follows:

---

```
I am Test thread:Thread OneOneOneOne
I am Test thread:Thread OneOneOneOne
I am Test thread:Thread OneOneOneOne
I am Test thread:Thread OneOneOneOne
I am in main now
I am Test thread:Thread OneOneOneOne
I am Test thread:Thread Two
I am Test thread:Thread Two
I am Test thread:Thread OneOneOneOne
I am Test thread:Thread Two
I am Test thread:Thread OneOneOneOne
I am Test thread:Thread Two
I am Test thread:Thread OneOneOneOne
I am Test thread:Thread Two
I am Test thread:Thread OneOneOneOne
I am Test thread:Thread Two
I am Test thread:Thread OneOneOneOne
I am Test thread:Thread Two
I am Test thread:Thread Two
I am Test thread:Thread Two
I am Test thread:Thread Two
I am in main now
```

and so on. Here is my code:

```
package com.rahul;

class ThreadTest implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        bar();
    }
    public synchronized void bar() {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.println("I am Test thread:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadTest(),"Thread OneOneOneOne");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadTest(),"Thread Two");
        t1.start();
        try{
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        t2.start();
        while(true){
            System.out.println("I am in main now");
            try {
                t2.join();
                Thread.sleep(4000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have *two instances* of `ThreadTest`. They have nothing to do with each other; you're not calling the same `bar()`

If you do this instead:

```
ThreadTest tt = new ThreadTest();
Thread t1 = new Thread(tt,"Thread OneOneOneOne");
Thread t2 = new Thread(tt,"Thread Two");
```

Then the two threads are sharing an instance of `ThreadTest` and only one thread will be able to call `bar()` at a time on that single instance.

Comment: Damn, I missed it. Thanks a lot Brian!

Answer (score 2):

Declaring the method to be  `synchronized` will not have the effect you expect. Each thread is synchronized on its own instance of `ThreadTest`, so the calls do not interact. You need to synchronized on a shared object for one thread to block another. For instance:

```
class ThreadTest implements Runnable{
    private static Object LOCK_OBJECT = new Object();
    @Override
    public void run() {
        bar();
    }
    public void bar() {
        synchronized (LOCK_OBJECT) {
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                System.out.println("I am Test thread:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you're synchronizing is being accessed by only one thread, since they are instance methods, so each thread is calling it's *own* bar method.

Maybe you want to declare the bar method as `static`.